# Access to mountpath variable from inside a template using express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Is there a clean, recomended way to access the mountpath from inside a template, so an express app can be run both standalone and as a part of another app (by means of app.use), with the paths pointing to the correct destination either way?

Something like:

```
{{mountpath}}route/to/file
```

So in the case that the app is running standalone, mountpath will be `/`, and in case is running as a submodule, mountpath could be `/foo/`

Note: I'm using handlebars.

Comment: Could you please explain me, what do you mean by 'another app'?

Comment: For example, I run an express server in my raspberry pi that holds a wiki (modified tiddlywiki 2), a RSS filter, a web scrapper to RSS posts, and so many more. I want to release each of them as standalone apps in the future, yet I want to be able to mount them in a main Express server, sharing one single port and perhaps access to some resources, and I'll get to them by routes: `/wiki/index` and `/rssfilter/doSomeAction`

Comment: Yes it is possible, so you can use them as separate modules under same project. You can create folder such as `app` then under that you can have `module1,module2..` in different folders. Access each module with separate routes such as `/module1/action1`,`/module1/action2`, `/module2/action1`,`/module2/action2` etc. Let me know if you need more detailed answer about implementing this in code.

Comment: Yeah, I currently do that, but the view templates contain things like:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/module1/css/icons-embedded.css">`, and that can't be run standalone, nor something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/icons-embedded.css">` would run inside a module... (this also applies to all the get and posts done in ajax, and all the links) so the paths must be dinamically completed on the view... that's the problem I'm solving

Comment: i understood what kind of answers you are looking for. Before writing answer for you, let me clarify first. So you have problem with mentioning paths of handlebar view templates which you render using your routes? There is a way to simplify and use a generalised path which i would write a detailed answer. Do i understood your question correctly now?

Comment: i got it buddy, thanks for making it clear :) i am writing answer for you.

Comment: The paths get along just fine, each module import their individual views with: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');` . The problem is with all the routes within the template itself... I need the URIs to match the correct destination, whether app is actually listening to a port, or being required and used from within another app

Comment: This is my best solution so far... yet, still missing something: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29553290/1423696

Answer (score 0):

express.static middleware is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application.
How it works:

- Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory

  // GET /style.css etc

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Mount the middleware at "/static" to serve static content only when their request path is prefixed with "/static"

  // GET /static/style.css etc.

  **app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Serve static files from multiple directories, but give precedence to "./public" over the others

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));**

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));**

In your case you can use the second case i.e.; mounting files on path '/static', so whatever files are under the folder public can be accesses with **src='/static/filename.xyz'**
Create a folder name public with sub folders css, js, images
Or if you want your css to be mounted on path `/css` then you do :

```
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'module1/css')));
```

Now you can use all your css files in your entire application as :

```
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, yet, the express.static is being called from inside each module, so `/` would end up being `/module1/`. I don't want to call a express.static from the mother app for each module (as is being called from the inside of each module already) , and that's why I was looking for a suggestion on a clean, elegant way to do this

Answer (score 0):

There is an [event that is fired after the module is mounted](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.onmount), so I can do:

```
app.locals.modulePath = "/";

app.on('mount', function (parent) {
  app.locals.modulePath = app.mountpath;
});
```

The locals are directly accessible from inside all the views, so this will be accessible like `{{modulePath}}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - needed to use mountpath from inside a template.

Solution that works for me is based on 2 facts

1. mountpath is available in request - req.baseUrl
2. response locals object gets exported to the template - res.locals

First, create a one-line middleware - this will apply to all routes inside the module/subapp

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.baseUrl = req.baseUrl;
    next();
});
```

Then inside the template use `#{baseUrl}/some/route` - note that this is jade syntax, but I suppose it works the same way with handlebars.