# Get access to Express mountpath from inside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In an attempt to build a truly modular express app (one that can run stand alone or as a part of another app) I need to find out the cleanest way to find the mount path from inside the subapp. For a short example, lets say that there are two files: main.js and subapp.js

***main.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var localApp = express();
var subapp = require('./subapp');

app.use('/foo', subapp);
app.use('/bar', localApp);
console.log(localApp.mountpath); // yes, this prints '/bar' as expected
...
```

***subapp.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var truePath = app.mountpath; // I wish this would point to '/foo', but instead points to '/'

...
module.exports = app;
```

What is the best way (as in cleanest) to find the mountpath from inside the module? I'm doing this trying to solve this problem: [Access to mountpath variable from inside a template using express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29552397/1423696) in a non hardwired way.

As shown in the example, tried already with app.mountpath without success

Answer (score 2):

As answered by alsotang, this is actually a problem of execution sequence, but it can be solved in what I think is a clean way. There is an [event that is fired after the module is mounted](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.onmount), so you can do:

```
var truePath = = "/";

app.on('mount', function (parent) {
  truePath = app.mountpath;
});
```

Where in real life *truePath* could be `app.locals.truePath`, so it can be accessed from inside the views.

Answer (score 0):

eh..It's a problem of execution sequence.

In your subapp.js, the `app.mountpath` statement is before `module.exports = app`.

But only you export the app, then the app be mounted, then it would be set the `mountpath` property.

so, you should retrieve `mountpath` after the app be mounted by outer express.

My suggestion are two:

1. set the mountpath in your subapp.js. And outer express read this property.
2. perhaps you think 1 is not truly modular. so you can alternatively define a config file. and both main.js and subapp.js read mountpath from the config.

Answer (score 0):

Try `req.baseUrl`:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var foo = require('./foo');

app.use('/foo', foo);

app.listen(3000);
```

**foo.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.baseUrl); // '/foo'
  res.send('foo');
});

module.exports = router;
```